# Unknown swift compiler error without additional info

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When compile, Xcode show error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'Int'
```

How to find out in which file at least this happens?

Comment: If you are just looking for where the error is, you can go to the left panel in Xcode, click the 5th tab from the left, which is shaped like a ⚠︎. It will show you all the errors and warning. Click on an error and it will bring you to the file.

Comment: @КириллЕмельянов You have to share code. where you getting error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is being thrown because the closure you're passing to then purports to return a Int, but no such value is ever returned. Otherwise you plan on returning a Int somewhere in that closure, you need to change the closure's return type to Void.

Comment: I found error, but I don't understand, why compiler not show error line explicitly :/

Comment: You don't need the return type or the return                                                 
  -> lnt in return

Comment: @КириллЕмельянов, because *that line with error is missing*, compiler can't highlight what *doesn't even exist*. That line should contain `return <some int>` or something like that.

Comment: @user28434 I understand, thanks